# Dealing with re-rendering and events

Tags: meteor

I'm using the meteorite plugin *pickadate* (a packaged jQuery plugin) in my code and I'm having trouble dealing with sessions, re-rendering, and displaying the calendars.

I have a template called *datepicker* that displays two tables that hold input boxes used to display the date in dd/mm/yyyy format, and also a calendar display area for the date in a more  visually pleasing format.

```
<template name="datePicker">
  <div class="dates">
    <table class="dateTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span class="checkDate"><input type="text" id="checkIn" name="checkIn" value="" placeholder="Check In"></span></th>
          <th><span class="checkDate"><input type="text" id="checkOut" name="checkOut" value="" placeholder="Check Out"></span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="dateTableBody">
        <tr>
          <td id="startDate">
            <span class="dayNum">{{startDateDayNum}}</span>
            <div class="monthYear">
              <span class="month">{{startDateMonth}}</span>
              <span class="year">{{startDateYear}}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="day">{{startDateDayName}}</span>
          </td>
          <td id="endDate">
            <span class="dayNum">{{endDateDayNum}}</span>
            <div class="monthYear">
              <span class="month">{{endDateMonth}}</span>
              <span class="year">{{endDateYear}}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="day">{{endDate}}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p class="welcomeRewards"><span class="wr">Welcome Rewards</span> <span class="nights">Collect <strong><b>1</b> nights</strong></span></p>
  </div>
</template>
```

I use helpers to set the start and end date values based on stored Session variables, for example:

```
Template.datePicker.startDateYear = function() {
  return Session.get('startDate').year;
}
```

Currently clicking on the *checkIn* input box should display the pickadate calendar, when a date is selected this updates my startDate session and populates the calendar display.

What I want now is for the *checkOut* calendar to open, but because the page has re-rendered if doesn't show on the page.

Here is my rendered method showing how I instantiate the calendars.

```
Template.datePicker.rendered = function() {
  var template = this;

  var checkOut = $('#checkOut').pickadate({
    weekdaysShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    today: '',
    clear: '',

    onClose: function(e) {
      Session.set('openEndDate', false);
      setDates(this, true);
      getNights(checkInPicker, this);
    }
  });
  var checkOutPicker = $('#checkOut').pickadate('picker');

  var checkIn = $('#checkIn').pickadate({
    weekdaysShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    min: true,
    today: '',
    clear: '',

    onClose: function(e) {
      var year = this.get('select').year,
          month = this.get('select').month,
          date = this.get('select').date;

      if (this.get()) {
        checkOutPicker.set({
          'min': [year,month,date+1],
          'max': [year,month,date+28]
        });

        setDates(this);

        Session.set('openEndDate', true);
      };
    }
  });

  var checkInPicker = $('#checkIn').pickadate('picker');

  this.tCheckIn = checkInPicker;
  this.tCheckOut = checkOutPicker;

  if(Session.get('openEndDate')) {
    this.tCheckOut.open();
  }
}
```

What is the meteor way to get this working?

Comment: IMHO, the "Meteor way to get this working" would just use an [HTML5 datepicker](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) and spend your time implementing other non-trivial things.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but without even Firefox support it's a no go for my project unfortunately.

Comment: Ah. That's too bad. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running meteor with:

```
meteor --release template-engine-preview-10.1
```

Or do:

```
meteor update --release template-engine-preview-10.1
meteor
```

This will use the latest preview release of the new templating engine, which has more fine grained control over reactively rendering HTML, allowing you to use most jQuery plugins normally. The new template engine will eventually be merged into the meteor core release before Meteor 1.0, at which point you can do:

```
meteor update
meteor
```

Note that the new engine does not need (and does not support) `{{#constant}}`, `{{#isolate}}`, or `preserve`, so if you have any you'll need to remove them.

Comment: So I'm struggling with this, I also use Iron-Router, so I had to use a shark branch to get my site loading, now I have template.base.js errors Exception in Meteor UI: Error: Expected valid attribute name, '', null, or object. I assume this is because of some old method Template method I'm using?

Comment: Ok after more refactoring I managed to get things working again, thank you, any idea when this will be released?

Comment: Some time in early 2014 https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/10/01/geoff-schmidt-at-devshop-8-getting-meteor-to-10